# Integration of a peaked multidimensional function

Tags: numerical-integration

I have the following function

```
PQ=p^2 + q^2 + μ - 2*p*q*(Cos[θp]*Cos[θq] + Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θp]*Sin[θq])
QK=k^2 + q^2 + μ - 2*k*q*Cos[θq]
KPQ=k^2 + p^2 + q^2 + 2*p*Cos[θp]*(k - q*Cos[θq]) - 2*q*(k*Cos[θq] + 
  p*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θp]*Sin[θq])

vol = p^2*q^2*Sin[θp]*Sin[θq]; 
denFreq = ω + (k^2 + q^2 + KPQ)/2; 
f[ω_, η_, k_, p_, q_, θp_, θq_, ϕ_, μ_] = vol*(1/PQ - 1/QK)*
  ((HeavisideTheta[kF - Sqrt[KPQ]]*denFreq)/(PQ*(denFreq^2 + η^2)))
```

where I introduced $\mu$ to regularize the divergence of the integrand.
I should check whether the integral converge to a finite limit when $\mu\rightarrow 0$.

So I tried to compute the following integral (for small $\mu$)

```
kF = 1.; 
ω0 = 0; 
η0 = 0.1; 
μ0 = 0.0001; 
k0 = 0.5; 
kcut = 10; 
NIntegrate[f[ω0, η0, k0, p, q, θp, θq, ϕ, μ0], {p, kF, kcut}, 
  {q, 0, kF}, {θp, 0, Pi}, {θq, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  Method -> "MonteCarlo"]
```

I tried different integration schemes (mainly different montecarlo schemes, including the Cuba library) but I obtain quite different results, since I guess even after the regularization with $\mu$ the function is not "well-behaved".

Which integration scheme is the most recommended for my case?
Taking smaller values of $\mu$ I find that the integral increases, but how can I be sure that it is the "real" behaviour of the function and not simply a consequence of a not converged numerical integration?

Any suggestion is welcome